# Are BIOS .exe update files Windows-version dependant?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, bios, fan

I was given an [old HP laptop](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/compaq-presario-f700-notebook-pc-series/3548233/model/3646831#Z7_3054ICK0K8UDA0AQC11TA930O2) (HP Compaq Presario F755US) which came with Widows Vista. Vista worked very slow and laggy so I decided to wipe it and install Ubuntu. Everything worked well, but since then, a few seconds after booting the PC, it turn off abruptly. So I can not reach the operating system, not even if I use an Ubuntu Live USB or a Windows Installation Disk. The only I can say is that after booting, I hear the fans turning off, and a few seconds later, the PC shuts down by itself.

I've [read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112395/what-might-cause-a-laptop-to-suddenly-turn-itself-off-while-running-ubuntu-but) that this issue might be caused because wiping the disk, delete some files that the computer uses to control the fans, so the computer gets hot and turns off. This issue might be solved updating the BIOS. My BIOS version is F.05 while the latest version is F.0A

The problem is that in order to update the BIOS, HP only provides a file called sp52463.exe, which must be run from Windows Vista exclusively (the OEM OS). But I can not run the file sp52463.exe since I can not get into Windows!!!

I've read that I could update the BIOS without enter to Windows, using a FreeDOS Live USB. So, I tried booting the PC from a FreeDOS Live USB and miraculously the computer didn't shut down (Can someone explain why FreeDOS boot while Windows and Ubuntu don't?). What I need now is to use FreeDOS to install the BIOS update, using the file sp52463.exe that HP provides.

The problem is that HP says the file sp52463.exe can only run from Windows Vista exclusively:

> This package contains the WinFlash Utility and a System BIOS image for the supported notebook models and operating systems. The WinFlash Utility is used to locally flash the System BIOS (ROM) on notebooks operating in a Microsoft Windows Vista environment.

So aparently, I can not run the sp52463.exe file from FreeDOS. I didn't make the try yet, because I've read that it might be dangerous to fail in a BIOS update. I was hoping that someone could tell me if this would work? Or is there another way to update the BIOS?

Comment: When the computer boots, go directly into the BIOS. Make sure the fans stay on while being in the bios. I have a feeling they'll turn off there too and this is a hardware problem.

Comment: When I'm in the BIOS, the fans stay on. Even when I start FreeDOS, the fans stay on. They just turn off when I start Windows 7 or Ubuntu, or any USB of Windows 7 or Ubuntu. Don't know what would happen with Windows Vista, because I couldn't find the Windows Vista DVD nor a legit link to download an ISO of Win Vista Home Basic 32 bits

Answer (score 2):

To use that BIOS flash utility, you will need Windows.  It is more than likely a 32 bit Windows application.  This means it wont execute in FreeDOS.

Contact HP support and check their forums, there might be alternative methods for flashing the BIOS.

As for "wiping the files that control the fans." That is pure bunk.  While modern OSs do have the ability to control the fans, so does the BIOS.  There are no "files" that control the fans.